# Why does my code block give an error, but running the individual lines doesn't?

Tags: r, file, block

This block in my code:

```
library(clam)
library(maps)
dat = read.table('HPM/treatR/props_with_calib_dates_vacc.csv', sep = ',', header = T)
```

returns the error

> "cannot open file 'HPM/treatR/props_with_calib_dates_vacc.csv': No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"

yet, if I run each line individually, they work fine. What gives?

**SOLVED**

```
library(clam)
library(maps)
setwd("~/")
print(getwd())
dat = read.table('HPM/treatR/props_with_calib_dates_vacc.csv', sep = ',', header = T)
```

I had set the wd through the session tab, but for some odd reason it didn't take. Adding setwd and then the print function to double check, I got it to work.

**SOLVED BETTER**

Since this .rmd uses Knitr, I was able to add the working directory into the setup chunk. I learned this when my previous solution resulted in an error telling me to do this instead.

```
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "~/")
```

Comment: Are you running this in Rscript or R markdown?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going on from this description. Maybe add `print(getwd())` before the read.table to see what the current directory is when the code is run. Chances are the current directory is different in the two contexts you are running the code. Are you using RStudio? How exactly are you running the code block?

Comment: @Onyambu as far as I know, I don't use either of those things. I have R 4.0.2 and Rstudio. Should I be using one of those instead?

Comment: @MrFlick fixed! Even though I was going into session and changing the wd, for some reason it didn't work. Editing my post now

Comment: You definitely MUST be using one of 1) Rscript, 2) Console, 3) Rmarkdown. Google to see what what they mean. This is not a Cosole problem since you said that running the code line by line works. So its either you are using the script or markdown.

Comment: @Onyambu this script is a .rmd (R markdown?) file, not a .r file (Rscript?) am I assuming those connections correctly?

Comment: @Alexis well then, the reason why its not working is because the rmd file directory is different from the working directory